# Getting random single document from Firestore in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

So, I have created data with a list of documents on Firestore, and I want to retrieve a single document randomly, whenever the Android activity is invoked.

Like for example, I have the following set of documents in the collection "people"

Alex

Abhishek

Nandini

Nancy

and in my Android activity, I have a TextView which will show each of the collection name randomly, whenever I invoke that activity, like when I open the activity, it will show "Nancy" on the textview and again when I reopen, it would show "Abhishek!"

Hope you understood my question, and it will be helpful and anyone can help me in that

Using JAVA code for coding my Android application!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think firebase can get a random doc.
You should use a field in your documents to handle that.

For example: if your application is simple, using an incremental number in each document should be enough as you could simply query a random number between 0 and the number of documents-1

Comment: like see all the documents are retrieved using collectionreference, and using for each, we get every document, I want to retrieve one single document in random on android studio!

Answer (score 0):

Retrive all the documents and store them in an arraylist and when user clicks the textview, pick a random document from the list.
`ArrayList.random()` this returns a random element from the list.

Comment: I tried using random() in the arraylist but it shows, method random is not resolved
like I created an arraylist questionlist and I wrote the code as follows - 'questionlist.random()' which is not working!